# Find the count of element in a sequence way in swift?

Tags: swift

This is the array of elements:

```
let numbers = [7, 7, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7]
```

and the output will be in the given form

```
[2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
```

I tried this method:

```
for item in numbers {
    let trueCount = numbers.filter { $0 == item }.count
    print("\(item) Total Count is \(trueCount)")
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: I don't think it is fully clear how the output was computed. Can you edit the question so it is more clear?

Comment: Is this a school assignment? Check out reduce: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce especially https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126956-reduce

Comment: can you help please

Comment: First you need to understand the assignment, look at the expected output and try to figure out what to do. Then try to write the code for it.

Comment: if seven comes two times then the number is append on array then 6 comes two times then the number is append in array is 2 like . i have to count the element in sequence

Comment: Then why don't you try to do that?

Comment: i tried but never get the answer because i am new in swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is something like that:

```
let input = [7,7,6,6,4,4,4,5,5,7]

let reduced = input.reduce(into: [(value: Int, count: Int)]()) { acc, value in
    if (acc.last?.value == value) {
        acc[acc.count - 1].count += 1
    } else {
        acc.append((value: value, count: 1))
    }
}
let counts = reduced.map { $0.count }

print(counts)
```

Output:

```
[2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: @DynamoPRo did that helped ?

Comment: It would be much easier to just keep the last value in a var instead of creating a tuple collection. `var last: Int?` `let reduced: [Int] = input.reduce(into: []) {` `if last == $1 {` `$0[$0.index(before: $0.endIndex)] += 1` `} else {` `last = $1` `$0.append(1)` `}` `}`

Comment: love you @ndelanou life saver Answer

Comment: @LeoDabus I think you're right. Your solution is simpler